# Can we construct general counterexample to support the Weak Whitney theorem?

Tags: gn.general-topology, differential-topology

Can we construct an example for the weak Whitney theorem to illustrate the existence of a continuous function from an $n$-dimensional manifold to an $m$-dimensional manifold that cannot be smoothly embedded for approximation when $n<m\le 2n$, for any $n<m\le 2n$?

Hirsch ([1] p. 27) says that the approximation version cannot be improved and gives a simple counterexample which is not our expected because it is not general for $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$:

$S^1$ is mapped into $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that the image curve crosses itself like what happens figure 8,  no sufficiently close approximation can be injective.

**Reference**

[1] Morris W. Hirsch, *[Differential topology](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-9449-5)* (English), Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 33. New York - Heidelberg - Berlin: Springer-Verlag, pp. x+221 (1976), [MR1336822](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1336822), [Zbl 0356.57001](https://zbmath.org/0356.57001).

Comment: I think you should have edited this question rather than ask a new one (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455253/can-we-construct-a-general-counterexample-to-support-the-weak-whitney-embedding).  I've flagged both for moderator attention to figure out how to merge them.